# How to crop Facebook profile picture without losing the quality of it?

Tags: image-quality

I have JPEG picture and I want to upload it in Facebook as a profile picture. How do I crop it without losing the quality of the picture? I have tried so many options but none worked.

Comment: Please do not deliberately post off-topic questions here. You might be able to get some support at Super User, but do not request any special attention - most people are volunteers here.

Answer (score 0):

Well images get scaled down or are already scaled down to save size on the server and also to not have croping issues. So what I would say is to use Photoshop to take the image and change the dimensions of the image to the Facebook dimensions then you can have a perfect one. You will lose quality if you are scaling it up but if you are scaling it down then you should have the quality still be the same. If you do not have Photoshop you can use Pixler or something like that.
Good luck. :)

Comment: Ahhmm... The Facebook dimensions are 160pix  160pix right?

Comment: It doesn't work that i've made the picture 180px(height) and 180px(width) and the it's still cropping my picture?